# Organizing extensions for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, organizer

You can use Visual Studio (MSVS) for Python, C++, Qt, C#, Fortran, etc. projects. Each of them requires just right set of enabled extensions and all others preferably disabled and hidden.

Is there a tool to simplify extensions switch in "Manage Extensions" window? For example, pack them in folders, workspaces/presets. Cloning VM's is a bit too heavy and slow solution.
Hiding all unused is especially desirable when you try to experiment with a new tool.

Current alternative is disabling/enabling them manually every major project switch.

To specify which window is supposed to be improved:

[image]

Comment: There is no way to implement this functionality, maybe you can request a feature on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest).

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Just hard to believe this was not addressed previously. But you practically gave correct answer on my question: "Visual Studio questions currently belong not to SO, but to very well made MS dev community QA tracker https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio"